# T&P relief valve's probe size issue - can I use a shorter exposed probe to replace a long one

Tags: water-heater

Please check the below picture, can I use a longer neck of T&P valve which has shorter exposed probe compare with my old to replace it?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: No, probe length relates to function. Even if it had the same temp. rating the location of the probe in the tank would be different. Use one with the probe position closest to the original. If you can't find one with the same ratings and configuration of the original, you should reach out to the manufacturer of the appliance for a replacement. Why are you proposing to use the "long-neck" one?

Comment: the short one is not able to screw enough as its neck is short, so the most part is left over the outside.

Comment: the second one's exposed probe is actually one inch shorter than my original one, I think that should be fine, right? @JimmyFix-it

Comment: No. The probe should be the same length as the original to ensure it gets the right amount of water contact. A little longer should be OK as long as it fits in the tank properly but shorter isn't OK.

Comment: 2 cm difference there, is this fine? @HazardousGlitch

Comment: I have attached the model spec. My original one is NCLX-5S, the one I'm trying to use is NCLX-5LX. the different for "E" which is the length of exposed probe is around 2cm, is this fine? @HazardousGlitch

Comment: Finally, I installed the one with the longer probe that I have to peel off the cover on the hole so that I can install it. Thanks to all you guys. @HazardousGlitch

Comment: and @JimmyFix-it

Answer (score 1):

The T&P probe should be the same length as the original to make sure it has the same contact with the water. Longer should be OK as long as it fits properly but shorter is not.

Comment: If a valve has been previously replaced with one with a longer probe, then it must be safe,  on the next replacement, to use a valve with a probe shorter then the one currently installed, as long as it is longer then the original one. If you only have the valve that is currently installed,  how do you find out the original/minimum probe length?